# converting perl regular expressions to python

Tags: python

I'm trying to change some lines of perl to python and I'm struggling to understand
what's going on in the perl code. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

thanks!

```
    my($junk1, $filename, $junk2) = $mydir =~ m/(.*\\)(.*\\)(.*)/;
    $filename =~ s/\\//;
        print $out $filename, "\n";
```

Comment: I'm not clear on the first "$mydir" and how that is then passed so that it can be parsed/ formatted by the regular expression

Comment: This is painful. Is this the equivalent of the my $mydir = shift @ARGVdef pop_func(*args): 
  return args.pop(0)

Comment: I'm beginning to think I need to re-think my approach to this and take more advantage of the fact that I have python at my disposal instead of a straight up port.

Comment: The second bit you added is just globbing the directory of text files. This is easy in Python too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first line (with `m/(.*\\)(.*\\)(.*)/` splits `$mydir` into three components, the first two ending in backslash.

For example if `$mydir` was `Asdf\fdsa\jkl`, the first line sets `$junk1 = Asdf\`, `$filename = fdsa\`, `$junk2 = jkl`.

The line

```
$filename =~ s/\\//;
```

takes `$filename` (`fdsa\`) and removes the last backslash (the syntax is `s/stuff_to_match/stuff_to_substitute_with/`).

In python you can use the [`re` module](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) to do regex stuff, or in this case it looks like you could just split on backslash, removing the need for regex.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use regular expressions to chop up file paths.

Instead, use the [`os.path` module](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html) and string functions. In particular, the `os.path` module accounts for a lot of the differences between operating systems (directory separators - unix `/` vs. windows `\\`, etc.) This makes your code a bit more likely to work on different computers.

```
>>> mypath = "D:\\lws\\vc\\.git\\objects\\dd"

>>> mydir = os.path.dirname(mypath)
>>> mydir
'D:\\lws\\vc\\.git\\objects'

>>> dirs = mydir.split(os.path.sep) # On windows, os.path.sep is `\\`.
>>> dirs
['D:', 'lws', 'vc', '.git', 'objects']

>>> dirs[0:2]
['D:', 'lws']

>>> filename = os.path.basename(mypath)
>>> filename
'dd'
```

Comment: I think I get where you're going with this.

Comment: Can you help me a bit more in terms of using this for the above perl code?

Comment: @user1124541: I don't know Perl. ;) More seriously, can you clarify what you actually want to do? Then we can solve the problem directly, instead of trying to port Perl to Python.

Comment: me neither :) i'm trying to format some files and I have a perl file that does what I need, but it's inconvenient given the larger scope of  my task.

Answer (score 1):

`my($junk1, $filename, $junk2) = $mydir =~ m/(.*\\)(.*\\)(.*)/;`

This either (incorrectly) tries to get the file name or, actually, gets the containing folder of the target file.

`$filename =~ s/\\//;`

Removes any leading or trailing path separators. It is poorly written Perl BTW since it does not check success or failure of the regex.

So, this is the result:

```
my $mydir="c:\\music\\ap\\mahadeva.mp3";    
my($junk1, $filename, $junk2) = $mydir =~ m/(.*\\)(.*\\)(.*)/;
$filename =~ s/\\//;
print $filename, "\n";
```

Prints: `ap`

A literal translation into Python re is:

```
import re

mydir="c:\\music\\ap\\mahadeva.mp3"

m=re.search(r'(.*\\)(.*\\)(.*)', mydir)
if m:
    print re.sub(r'\\', '', m.group(2))
```

Well not a PERFECT translation, because the Python checks for a match and the Perl version does not.

There are much easier ways to do this in Python though (and Perl for that matter). You could do this:

```
 print p.split('\\')       # ['c:', 'music', 'ap', 'mahadeva.mp3']

 print p.split('\\')[-2]   # prints 'ap'
```